# Do clouds get hotter while producing raindrops and snowflakes?

Tags: thermodynamics, climate-science, meteorology

I know that in clouds water particles condensate to form raindrops. I believe surface energy should be released in form of thermal energy. Will this newly created thermal energy increase the average temperature of cloud system or is there some fault in my line of thinking.

I also think if this is true then clouds forming snow should produce even more heat, as snow formation will release Latent heat in addition.
Can this be the reason that atmospheric temperature during snowfall doesn't feel like subfreezing chily because clouds become warmer?
(Sorry if all this is silly I've never seen a snowfall)

Comment: 1/2 Yeah i tend to agree. Steam forming into liquid is exothermic, meaning it gives off energy (generally as heat), and so is freezing. The only reason i hesitate instead of answering below is that raindrops dont come from steam condensing. I think the process of clouds and raindrops involves tiny particles like dust? Im almost positive that snow would warm a cloud. That seems more clear. Also, remember they leave the cloud and fall, so they take their low-energy status away from the cloud, increasing the average energy and hence temperature.

Comment: 2/2 “Can this be the reason that atmospheric temperature during snowfall doesn't feel like subfreezing chily because clouds become warmer?” **No**. The mass of snow is *tiny* compared to the earth’s atmosphere, even just in the area if the snowfall. Also, we are on the ground, so cold snow falling on us would make the air at lower elevations colder and higher ones warmer, as we just said it warms up the clouds. Snow is wonderful. 

Comment: Thanks @AI Brown. The reason i said snowfall doesn't feel sub zero is because I was thinking warmer clouds will emit some infrared towards the ground to keep us warm when we're outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments point out, you are correct that any phase change involves thermal transfer. When the water goes from either pure vapor (gas) or microparticles of liquid (clouds are really weird!!!) to raindrops or to solid water, energy is released.
However, this is not why things seem warmer when there is snow.  The earth radiates energy per black-body rules, but a cloud cover reflects a lot of this energy back down.  In winter, this produces a small warming effect.  But in summer, the amount of solar irradiation that the clouds block is much greater than the reflected earth-radiation, so in general you feel cooler under clouds than in direct sunlight.